# Python pandas dataframe and excel: Add cell background color

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, pandas-styles

Currently I save my dataframe like this

```
writer = ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
test_df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

And resulted excel file looks like this

```
cus  1  abc 2 jbd 3 lkl ...
1   col  v  v  v  v  v ...
2    v   v col v  v  v ... 
3    v   v  v  v col v ...
```

What I need is that, when `cus` value `==` header value, that cell should have a green background. In example above, all cells with value col should be set green background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

There is [a new feature in Pandas 0.20.0 - `Excel output for styled DataFrames`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#excel-output-for-styled-dataframes):

```
styled = (df.style
            .applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v=='col' else ''))
styled.to_excel('d:/temp/styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works well in notebook. If I run the same code in spyder. It complains that 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_excel'. Any idea?

Comment: @JasonLi, please check that you have the same environment (versions, settings) when using `spyder` ...

Comment: Is it possible to apply multiple styles to a single dataframe ? How can I color the headers with different color . I want to know more about styling . Not able to find much on internet . Help please.

Comment: @MahaveerJangir, please check the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the StyleFrame library to achieve this.

To install

```
pip install styleframe
```

The documentation of this library can be found [here](http://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Try the following code to check whether it works to serve your purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

df = pd.DataFrame(" Your Dataframe ")

sf = StyleFrame(df)
style = Styler(bg_color='green') 
for col_name in df.columns:
    sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf.loc[sf['col_name']== col_name ], cols_to_style=col_name,
                          styler_obj=style)
sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

Cheers!

Comment: what happens if you have multiple sheets