# color specific cells in excel python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd, pandas.excelwriter, styleframe

i have 2 dataframes, from which i have to identify a difference in cells. Wherever i will find a difference, i have to change color of that cell(background color) in first dataframe aswell as in second dataframe.
In my case first dataframe cell has to be colored with #FFCCCC and second with #DAF6FF. The output of these dataframes has to be saved in two different excel files.

i have tried with these answers: https://kanoki.org/2019/01/02/pandas-trick-for-the-day-color-code-columns-rows-cells-of-dataframe/

[Python pandas dataframe and excel: Add cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365676/python-pandas-dataframe-and-excel-add-cell-background-color/44365941)

All these talks about using openpyxml with styled. My challenge is i have to update those cells which has changes in comparison phase itself and that(coloring) has to be reflected in excel output.
How do i achieve this ? hope some one would help me out here to get the right and better method.

Note: my data is huge is size(around 10000 lines in row columns).

Input:

DF1:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Yes | BNG |
| 12 | PE | CHN |
| 30 | LIKE | DHL |

DF2:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | No | BNG |
| 13 | PE | CHI |
| 30 | SNM | DHL |

Output Has to be in excel with cells colored like this.
[image]

My code is here:

'''

```
def split_compare_differ_df(difference_in_df):
    bg_delete = "background-color: red"
    bg_insert = "background-color: blue"
    unique_of_df1 = df1
    unique_of_df2 = df2
    for i in unique_of_df1.itertuples():
        for j in unique_of_df2.itertuples():
            if i[1] == j[1]:
                for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(i, j)):
                    x=list(i)
                    y=list(j)
                    if not idx ==0:
                        if a == b:
                            x[idx] = a
                            y[idx] = b
                            print(f'Index {idx} match: {a}')
                        else:
                            x[idx] = '{}{}'.format(bg_delete,a)
                            y[idx] = '{}{}'.format(bg_insert, b)
                            print(f'Index {idx} no match: {a} vs {b}')
#                             targetFileActiveSheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).fill = PatternFill(bgColor='FFEE08', fill_type = 'solid')
                    i = tuple(x)
                    j = tuple(y)

                i_list = list(i)
                i_list = i_list[1:]
                i_tuple = tuple(i_list)
                j_list = list(j)
                j_list = j_list[1:]
                j_tuple = tuple(j_list)
                unique_of_df1.loc[i[0]] = i_tuple
                unique_of_df2.loc[j[0]] = j_tuple
    return(unique_of_df1,unique_of_df2)
```

'''

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: @CharlieClark i have updated with my code..

Answer (score 1):

The comparison code can be simplified by generating a "diff matrix":

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

sf1 = StyleFrame({'col1': [10, 12, 30], 'col2': ['Yes', 'PE', 'LIKE'], 'col3': ['BNG', 'CHN', 'DHL']})
sf2 = StyleFrame({'col1': [10, 12, 30], 'col2': ['No', 'PE', 'SNM'], 'col3': ['BNG', 'CHI', 'DHL']})

sf1_diff = Styler(bg_color='#FFCCCC')
sf2_diff = Styler(bg_color='#DAF6FF')

ne = sf1.data_df != sf2.data_df

print(ne)
```

Now `ne` is a diff matrix containing `True` where there is a difference between the 2 dataframes:

```
    col1   col2   col3
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2  False   True  False
```

Now all we have to do is to style the original frames accordingly:

```
for col in ne.columns:
    sf1.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=ne[ne[col]].index,
                               styler_obj=sf1_diff,
                               cols_to_style=col)
    sf2.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=ne[ne[col]].index,
                               styler_obj=sf2_diff,
                               cols_to_style=col)

sf1.to_excel('sf1.xlsx').save()
sf2.to_excel('sf2.xlsx').save()
```

And we end up with `sf1.xlsx`:

[image]

and `sf2.xlsx`:

[image]

If you want both frames on the same sheet you can use

```
writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
sf1.to_excel(writer)
sf2.to_excel(writer, startcol=len(sf1.columns) + 2)
writer.save()
```

Comment: i tried first phase of your solution, which suggests to get compare output in object 'ne'. However its not working for me as it says "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects", here i can't drop my index column as it required for further processing... @DeepSpace