# How to highlight differences between the two data frames in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames with identical columns in pandas,
we have index at column A

Actual:

```
  A      B       C 
  1     apple   red
  2     berry   blue 
  3    grapes   green
```

second data frame

Expected:

```
  A    B     C
  1   apple  green
  2   guava  blue
  3   grapes  green
```

Now I need to compare the two data frames and highlight mismatched cells with in data frame and then export the output to excel.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.concat([actual,expected,expected]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)]).to_excel(.......)
```

output:

```
  A   B   C
  1  apple red
  2  berry blue
```

I need to highlight red and berry

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function - `compare`, which help you to compare two datasets:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": ["apple", "berry", "grapes"],
        "C": ["red", "blue", "green"]
    },
    columns=["A", "B", "C"])

df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[0, 'C'] = 'green'
df2.loc[2, 'B'] = 'guava'
```

Using it, you get the comparison of two datasets:

```
df.compare(df2)
```

gives you:

```
    B               C
    self    other   self    other
0   NaN     NaN     red     green
2   grapes  guava   NaN     NaN
```

By filtering out unneeded rows (that are the same) and columns you can get DataFrame with only data that differ from original dataframe:

```
compare = df.compare(df2, keep_shape=True).drop('other', level=1, axis=1)
compare = compare.droplevel(1, axis=1).dropna(how='all')

    A   B       C
0   NaN NaN     red
2   NaN grapes  NaN
```

Because we need to filter the rows that are the same from original dataset:

```
filtered = df.loc[compare.index]
```

Now, with that, we can "highlight" the differing data somehow:

```
def color_cells(s):
    if pd.notna(s):
        return 'color:{0}; font-weight:bold'.format('red')
    else:
        return ''

filtered.style.apply(lambda x: compare.applymap(color_cells), axis=None)
```

Which should produce something like that:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is what I would do also.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with StyleFrame as shown in this post: [color specific cells in excel python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584213/color-specific-cells-in-excel-python).

First, run pip install styleframe. Then follow the below steps:

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler
import pandas as pd

# true and expected data
d_true = {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['apple', 'berry', 'grapes'], 'C':['red', 'blue', 'green']}
df_true = pd.DataFrame(d_true)

d_exp = {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['apple', 'guava', 'grapes'], 'C':['green', 'blue', 'green']}
df_exp = pd.DataFrame(d_exp)

# pass df to styleFrame 
sf1 = StyleFrame(df_true)
sf2 = StyleFrame(df_exp)

# Set color for differences 
sf1_diff = Styler(bg_color='#FFCCCC') # red
sf2_diff = Styler(bg_color='#DAF6FF') # blue

# Difference matrix 
ne = sf1.data_df != sf2.data_df

# apply above color style where difereneces are true
for col in ne.columns:
    sf1.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=ne[ne[col]].index,
                               styler_obj=sf1_diff,
                               cols_to_style=col)
    sf2.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=ne[ne[col]].index,
                               styler_obj=sf2_diff,
                               cols_to_style=col)

# save your excel 
sf1.to_excel('df1_diff_in_color.xlsx').save()
sf2.to_excel('df2_diff_in_color.xlsx').save()
```

Output excel file:

[image]